# ObjectId converting to strings in api, nodejs to reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, http, axios

I have a simple API, that sends data in a response

```
Food.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        res_id: restaurant._id
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$category",
        foods: {
            $push: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}], function(err, foods) {

    if (err)
        res.json({
            error: "error"
        });
    else
        res.json(foods);

});
```

However, when I read the data using `axios` in my React app, The `objectIds` get converted to strings in my front end React app.

Now I could not find any resource on the type of data types that can be passed over HTTP or any other restrictions. Can anyone point me to any resource or tell me if this is the way HTTP works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` will recursively call toJSON() method to get JSON-safe string representation of the object that you need to pass over HTTP from your server to your frontend app during serialization in javascript.

ObjectID will be converted to **24 byte hex string** during serialization: 
[ObjectID.prototype.toJSON](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/node_modules_bson_lib_bson_objectid.js.html#line213)

Comment: Does that mean objectIDs will always be received as strings in my frontend !?

Comment: @TanmoyBasak yes